# Can't run terminal(Visual Studio) to read c++ inputs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Thats what I see:

igorz@DESKTOP-QKLDJRN MINGW64 /c/Websites/cpp-series
$ cd "c:\Websites\cpp-series" && g++ gigel.cpp -o gigel && "c:\Websites\cpp-series"gigel
bash: cd: c:\Websites\cpp-series" && g++ gigel.cpp -o gigel && c:Websitescpp-series"gigel: No such file or directory

Thats the code(but the problem is'nt in code I think)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? That makes lot of a difference!

Comment: Make sure that the path that you put your code in has no spaces in the file names or folders. Remember that c++ compiles on the command line or shell and that in either of these a space will separate arguments. To get around this you need to quote your paths however its best to avoid the problem in the first place. If this is not the problem it could be that your Antivirus deleted your executable or you did not save your cpp file. You need to investigate the contents of your code folder.

Comment: Have you saved your code? Does running g++ gigel.cpp -o gigel.exe on the terminal work?

Comment: This `c:Websitescpp-series"gigel` looks like backslashes were used as escape characters, either for the script or only for the error output and your quotation marks seem to end at the directory. Do you have a make script or where does this command come from? It is probably not ported to Windows correctly